# How to store and recall the last radio button clicked in a session variable

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display text based on which radio button a user has clicked. I am having trouble using sessions to do this. When I use the following code, only the information related to the radio button that was first clicked is displayed (e.g., if someone clicks on radion button "A," then changes his mind and clicks on radio button "B," the session seems to think "A" is still clicked.

Any suggestions?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label for="choice1">Choice 1</label>
  <input class="selection" id="choice1" type="radio" name="selection"  value="choice1"/>

<div class="radio">
  <label for="choice2">Choice 2</label>
  <input class="selection" id="choice2" type="radio" name="selection"  value="choice2" />
</div>
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
$_SESSION['formStarted'] = true;
//...

if(($_SESSION['selection']) == 'choice1'){echo 'Text to be included only if choice 1 was selected.';}
```

Comment: what code do you use to retrieve the value?

Comment: @Dagon I apologize, but I'm fairly new to all of this. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['selection'] = isset($_POST[selection]) ? $_POST[selection] : 'choice1';
```

OR $_GET or $_REQUEST

Comment: Will this allow me to determine which button was checked, and then display text based on that selection?